# User who is logged in simultaneously from different browser ... how to forcely logout the first user

Tags: spring, spring-security

> User who is logged in simultaneously from different browser ... how to
>   forcely logout the first user
>
> i added some code like security configuration details just check

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
            securedEnabled = true,
            jsr250Enabled = true,
            prePostEnabled = true
    )
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
        @Bean
        public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
            return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
        }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

> i am thinking to tried with session but not working

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum where you put questions and expect complete solutions. You need to do implementation by yourself and then ask him something is not working as expected. You can mention what went wrong or what you were trying to do.

Comment: i added some code check please

Answer (score 2):

Use can use [maximumSessions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-security.html#spring-security-concurrent-sessions)(1) for this.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.authorizeRequests()
             .sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                    .expiredUrl("/session-expired") 
                    .and()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                    .invalidSessionUrl("/")
                    .sessionFixation().none();
}
```

Comment: You can read more at https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-security.html#spring-security-concurrent-sessions